# Advanced java : about statement interface

Tags: design-patterns

What does this mean ? Statement st=con.CreateStatement();
how method of Statement interface is accessed by Connection interface reference con ? please help me to understand the concept...

Comment: I think without more context is impossible to get the relationships between Connection and Statement classes to explain anything.  Can you be more verbose with your question?

Answer (score 0):

No method of `Statement` is accessed in this code.  A method of the `Connection` interface which creates a `Statement` instance is accessed, which is not particularly unusual, but is a example of a [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

See the javadoc for [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement())